# Change the Value on Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql-server

I need assistance on how to code duplicate Line IDs for the same Purchase Order and assign the additional line IDs with a new number. I would like to use Line ID + 100 for the additional duplicate rows. For example if Purchase Order #11 has three Line ID #5s then the first would stay as 5 and the second would be 501 and the third would be 502, however, I can only get a 1, 2 or 3 or if no duplicate just 1. I am not sure what to use to increment. I am hoping some one can assist or guide. Thank you

```
PurchaseOrderID   LineID   PackingList  NewLineID  
11                1        12323        1  
11                1        78786        2    
11                2        67523        1    
11                3        44559        1    
11                4        44559        1    
11                5        96545        1    
11                5        12323        2    
11                5        34569        3
```

The Packing Slip causes the duplicates for the same line ID.

Below is what I am trying to use which is giving me the above NewLineID:

```
SELECT 
  PurchaseOrderID, 
  LineID, 
  PackingList, 
  ROW_NUMBER() over
  (
      partition by PurchaseOrderID, LineID
      order by PurchaseOrderID, LineID
  ) as NewLineID 
FROM PurchaseOrderTransactions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` and `CASE`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT 
        PurchaseOrderID, 
        LineID, 
        PackingList, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PurchaseOrderID, LineID ORDER BY LineID)
    FROM PurchaseOrderTransactions
)
SELECT
    PurchaseOrderID, 
    LineID, 
    PackingList, 
    NewLineID = CASE 
                    WHEN RN = 1 THEN LineID
                    ELSE (LineID * 100) + (RN - 1)
                END
FROM Cte
```

---

Without using a CTE:

```
SELECT 
    PurchaseOrderID, 
    LineID, 
    PackingList, 
    NewLineID = 
        CASE
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PurchaseOrderID, LineID ORDER BY LineID) = 1 THEN LineID
            ELSE (LineID * 100) + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PurchaseOrderID, LineID ORDER BY LineID) - 1)
        END
FROM PurchaseOrderTransactions
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/13d13/1/0)

```
| PurchaseOrderID | LineID | PackingList | NewLineID |
|-----------------|--------|-------------|-----------|
|              11 |      1 |       12323 |         1 |
|              11 |      1 |       78786 |       101 |
|              11 |      2 |       67523 |         2 |
|              11 |      3 |       44559 |         3 |
|              11 |      4 |       44559 |         4 |
|              11 |      5 |       96545 |         5 |
|              11 |      5 |       12323 |       501 |
|              11 |      5 |       34569 |       502 |
```